# How to generate Entity Framework migrations with multiple DbContext in single c# project?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, database-migration

Could I create multiple migrations to every different `dbContext` class in single project?

I have a repository project which provide multiple `dbContext` classes to different project usage.

How should I manage these `dbcontext` migrations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the Context(Type) in [all commands](https://coding.abel.nu/2012/03/ef-migrations-command-reference/) with the `-ContextTypeName <string>` parameter.